# Conditional value declaration of annotated nullable type throws 'type inference failed'

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to conditionally declare a value of type `@Composable (() -> Unit)?` like this:

```kotlin
val myComposable: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = { /* something */ }.takeIf { condition }
```

The reason is because I wanted to use Compose's `ListItem` with the `secondaryText` parameter:

```kotlin
// Jetpack compose component
@Composable
fun ListItem(
  secondaryText: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
  // ...
)
```

```kotlin
// My Usage
ListItem(
  secondaryText = { /* something */ }.takeIf { condition == true }
)
```

But it turns out doing this throws following error:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is (() -> Unit)? but @Composable() (() -> Unit)? was expected
```

I later realized this code compiles:

```kotlin
val secondaryText: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = if (condition) {
  null
} else {
  { /* something */ }
}
```

What's the difference between these two declarations and why does the former cause a type inference failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `{ /* something */ }`, you create a value whose type is `() -> Unit`. Adding `.takeIf { condition }` will change the type to `(() -> Unit)?`. There's no info that this is a `@Composable`.

That's why your second approach worked: you've specified that you're creating a `@Composable`.

You can work around that by explicitly stating that you are working with a `@Composable`:

```kotlin
ListItem(
    secondaryText = (@Composable { /* something */ }).takeIf { condition }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work the other way. The annotation is explicitly declared in the `ListItem`'s `secondaryText` parameter (`secondaryText: @Composable (() -> Unit)?`), so why do I have to type it out again? Shouldn't kotlin infer it for me?